# How can I change the font size in GnuCash on OS X?

Tags: macos, gnucash

How can I change the font size in GnuCash on OS X? I wasn't able to find anything in the preferences.

I tried using 'gconftool-2' on '~/.gconf' where GnuCash stores its GTK settings, but I wasn't able to get it to read the settings directory.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I wasn't all there when I was posting.

Answer (score 9):

For GnuCash 3.x, you need to create a `gtk.css` in the directory `~/Library/Application\ Support/Gnucash/config/gtk-3.0` with the following contents:

```
* {
    font: 14pt arial, sans-serif;
}
```

or whatever CSS settings you may prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the font size by creating a `~/.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash`-file with the following contents:

```
style "font"
{
  font_name = "Arial Narrow 12"
}
widget_class "*" style "font"
gtk-font-name = "Arial Narrow 12"
```

Info taken from the official [FAQ](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q:_How_get_I_rid_of_strange_unreadable_characters_or_adjust_the_font_size)